# Android Emulator tried with RAM Sizes

Tags: android-virtual-device

Please help me.
I have installed Andoird in my 16GB Ram, I5 Processor laptop.

Everything went well but Emulator is never starting. 
I tried with different RAM sizes like 1536,950,512,700,600,800,1100,450,1450.
None worked.I am using CPU/ABI in X86_64, a shown below. Can you please suggest me something.

[AVD setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC9t7.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"I have installed Andoird", sounds like you want to use emulator for some other use than for development, if so than Android Emulator isn't that good as it is. If you're using it for development usage, then try to update the system images for API level 23
- the emulator may take upto 10 (or more) minutes to start
-confirm that emulator is running in Task manager,
also , API level 23 is quite new so It may contain bugs that are not known.